# Is it possible yet to use Decodable with Firestore Timestamps/Dates?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a dictionary that's a `[String: Bookmark]` but that createdAt is saved as a `Timestamp` and the decoder throws an error when trying to make sense of the `Date`

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSDate)'

```
struct Bookmark: Decodable {
    let messageId: String
    let messageCreatedAt: Date
}


JSONDecoder().decode([String: Bookmark].self, data: data)
```

Is there a way yet to make Swift's `Decodable` protocol play nicely with Firestore Timestamps?

Edit:

If I print the `[String: Any]` and then try to decode in the console like so

```
 ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : "messageCreatedAt"
    - value : 2018-11-27 20:59:11 +0000

po valueDict["messageCreatedAt"] as? Date
```

I get

```
▿ Optional<Date>
  ▿ some : 2018-11-27 20:59:11 +0000
    - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 565045151.531769
```

So it must be something in `Decodable` then that isn't able to identify and parse this?

Edit:

JSON is

```
{
  "messageId": "abc123",
  "messageCreatedAt": "2018-11-27 20:59:11 +0000"
}
```

Comment: Please, add JSON you're trying to parse to the question.

Comment: @user28434 added the json

Comment: fixed. date's in quotes

Comment: fixed. the json is coming from firestore, not something that a person created fwiw

Answer (score 1):

How is `JSONDecoder` is decoding dates is defined by value of [`.dateDecodingStrategy`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/2895216-datedecodingstrategy) property.

If you have to parse `Date` from a string you should use either [`.iso8601`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/datedecodingstrategy/iso8601) or [`.formatted(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/datedecodingstrategy/formatted) (or if your date format is really custom and complicated and/or weird you may to have use [`.custom(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/datedecodingstrategy/custom)).

Your date string is almost `ISO 8601` formatted (it only lacks `T` between date and time parts), but that's enough to fail.

So your best option here is to use `formatted(_:)`:

```
// Declare it somewhere and reuse single instance as much as possible, formatter initialization is quite expensive
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX") // Better to fix Locale here
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd kk:mm:ss Z"
```

And then

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(dateFormatter)
let bookmark = try decoder.decode(Bookmark.self, from: data) 

print(bookmark.messageCreatedAt, bookmark.messageCreatedAt.timeIntervalSince1970)
// prints "2018-11-27 20:59:11 +0000 1543352351.0"
```